# Ncurses - Blank Window That Wait for Button Press Before Initilizing my Window

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am currently using ncurses at an attempt to make a game. I am attempting to force the user to press ENTER on the keypad to start, but seem to be running into some problems. When I create a switch case for the choices, it won't show my splash screen window until I press a button. Without implementing any sort of user input, it shows the splash screen the instant the program is run.

I have included my main and my choices function. Functions such as totalInformation and gameTitle are just graphics and are not important.

My main:

```
int main(void)
{
initscr();
WINDOW * opening_screen;
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
noecho();
cbreak();
raw();
start_color();

int height, width, start_y, start_x;
width = 80;
height = 40;
start_y = 0;
start_x = 0;
init_pair(1, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_CYAN);

opening_screen = newwin(width, height, start_y, start_x);
refresh();

keypad(opening_screen, true);
choices(opening_screen);
wrefresh(opening_screen);

totalInformation();
wrefresh(opening_screen);

border('|', '|', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+');
wrefresh(opening_screen);

attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
gameTitle();
wrefresh(opening_screen);
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));

attron(A_BLINK);
mvaddstr(37, 24, "Press the ENTER key to continue");
attroff(A_BLINK);
wrefresh(opening_screen);

getch();
endwin();
}
```

My choice function:

```
void choices(WINDOW * screen)
{
int c = wgetch(screen);
switch(c)
{
    case 10:
        mvaddstr(3,3,"YOUVE PRESSED ENTER");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Right now, when this runs, a black screen starts off the program. After I press ENTER, my full screen pops up as well as "YOUVE PRESSED ENTER".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When curses starts up, the screen is initially blank, but the program has to refresh (repaint) the screen to get to that point.  The `wgetch` call repaints (and clears, on the terminal) the *`opening_screen`*, and then the `mvaddstr` call updates the main window `stdscr`.
Finally, the **`getch`** call refreshes (i.e., *repaints*) the main window **`stdscr`**, and obscures the other windows.